# Is there a common word for "Blocked" and "Blocking"?

Tags: common-word

The context for this question is for a task management system when one task can either block or get blocked by another Task.

An example of the kind of word I'm looking for is "Clusivity" for the words "Include" and "Exclude".

The closest I can think of is "Blockage".

Comment: “Clusivity” as you say, covers both include and exclude. Are you looking for something that covers both blocked and unblocked? Like *block state*?

Comment: Interference?..

Comment: A block could be placed by either side.

Comment: I'd say that though 'clusivity' is a word, it is rarely if ever used outside the linguistics domain, and an attempt to use it in a less specific way would violate Gricean maxims.

Comment: _Clusivity_ should also cover _occlude, conclude,_ and _recluse_, no doubt among others. So _clusivity_ means 'the property of being derived from the perfect stem of the Latin verb _claudo_'?

Comment: Voting to close because you have not shown us how you would like to use the word in a sentence.  If you edit your question I'm happy to retract my close vote.

Comment: *Thread state*, *process state*, or *task state* are the common terminology depending on the precise entity that has the state, [example with task state](https://www.freertos.org/RTOS-task-states.html). Not a very interesting response, I know.

Comment: There are two independent separate states here, with four combinations: blocking/not blocking and blocker/not a blocker. It's not clear why you would want a single world. Can you provide an example sentence? (If it's for a variable name, you're likely far better off tracking these as two booleans.)

Answer (score 0):

A general term might be missing. There are terms  with a large enough scope of applications or a restricted one, but I find none specific to this question.

"*Valving*" involves mostly  concrete (physical)  phenomenon, and none seem to be specific to logistics. ([ref.](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22valving%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=Qu2iYtmFN5KEaquOoeAJ&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwjZrsiGqaL4AhUSghoKHStHCJwQ8tMDegQIARBD&biw=974&bih=999&dpr=1))

> (SOED) **valving** A system or arrangement of valves; valves collectively; Also (*rare*) operation, *esp.* opening and shutting in the manner of a valve.

- ([Gas pipelines](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Federal_Register/y8BQt2mRo20C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22valving%22&pg=PA39403&printsec=frontcover)) MTB believes that an economic burden unmatched by safety benefits would be placed on those pipelines in sparsely populated areas if similar valving were required in those areas
- ([Power systems operation and control](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Electrical_Engineer_s_Reference_Book/N9z8BAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22valving%22&pg=SA17-PA32&printsec=frontcover))  Fast valving logic + timing 470 Turbi M | set- Fast valving turbine controllers
- ([electonics](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Proceedings_of_the_Trends_in_Electronics/FYRVAAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&bsq=%22valving%22&dq=%22valving%22&printsec=frontcover)) IEEE TENCON '93 / Beijing ABSTRACT A cooperative control of excitation and fast valving based on artificial neural networks is proposed in this paper , Two neural networks are used to coordinate excitation and fast valving control
- ([Biomedical applications](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Mems_for_Biomedical_Applications/8s5ZAgAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22valving%22&pg=PA161&printsec=frontcover)) Valving is essential to the centrifugal-driven LOC platform, allowing on/off control of fluidic movement through the integrated multiple stages.
- ([Linguistics](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Dysphagia_Assessment_and_Treatment_Plann/lvpqDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22valving%22&pg=PA110&printsec=frontcover)) Posterior Linguapalatal Valving Analysis:: Posterior linguapalatal or “retro-oral portal” (Bosma, 1957a, p. 901) valving is central to DSS analysis because, in this scheme, timing of all subsequent events is compared with the beginning
- ([Psychology](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/A_Practical_Guide_to_Caring_for_Children/DVcSBQAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22valving%22&pg=PA159&printsec=frontcover))   Steam-valving is a powerful and simple technique that allows you to help the child release the exploding pressure of the anger storm in small, containable blasts.

Therefore a new term such as "*task-valving*"  might be found to be a convenient name for this abstract concept.

Another term is "*gating*".

> ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/gating)) **gating** noun Cell Biology.
> the process by which a channel in a cell membrane opens or closes.

> (SOED) **gate**. *Electonics* Subject to the action of a gate; select  parts (of a signal) that occur within a given time interval or range of amplitude; switch by means of a gate circuit. Chiefly as *gated* ppl adj, *gating* vbl noun & ppl adj.

Again, the term would have  to be coined analogically (*task-gating*, *priority-gating*, …).